# ¿ Como llevar String de vencimiento de un Cookie a Date?

Tags: java, cookies

**Hola**

Mi problema es que necesito poder llevar un String el cual contiene la **expire date**  de una **Cookie** a la clase **Date**, para luego teniendo la **expire date** en tipo **Date** usándola para crear un objeto de la clase **Cookie**.

Anteriormente desde la clase **Date** lo hubiera podido lograr, pero actualmente este método esta desestimado.

```
String dateExp = "Fri Jul 08 14:58:01 CEST 2022";
Date date = new Date(dateExp);
```

Y no encuentro la forma actual de poder llevar este **String** a **Date** usando un **Formato de Fecha**. Este es el código que utilice pero me lo rechaza.

```
String dateExp = "Fri Jul 08 14:58:01 CEST 2022";
SimpleDateFormat objSDF = new SimpleDateFormat();    
Date date = objSDF.parse(dateExp);
```

**Gracias** y espero su apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

La excepción que te muestra es ParseException,  porque SimpleDateFormat no sabe en que formato es el string que le estas pasando, en el constructor de SimpleDateFormat recibe como primero parámetro un String (pattern) para que le puedas pasar el formato de fecha que estas tratando de convertir, pero en tu caso también necesitas pasarle el segundo parámetro que es de tipo Locale.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
String dateExp = "Fri Jul 08 14:58:01 CEST 2022";

SimpleDateFormat formatter5 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);

Date date5 = formatter5.parse(dateExp);

System.out.println(date5.toString());
```

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos!